# How can you recommend to check for a file's existence in an S3 bucket and send back when it does?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a user-generated content setup where users record audio in the browser and this gets sent to an S3 bucket where it is then processed via a trigger and ends up in another bucket. I would like to send this result back to the user when it is processed.

Can you recommend a way to do this in Javascript? Is there a special kind of method for this in the context of AWS? There would also need to be a way to handle errors too. Maybe the approach would check 3 times, and if unsuccessful, give up.

Comment: How long does it take to process a file?

Comment: What sends the file to Amazon S3? Could that same process poll for a response?

Answer (score 0):

A guess: When you upload the file to your own API (AWS API GATEWAY, triggering a Lambda that does processing, upload and returning a message) on the server side, you could utilize a web worker with a callback function on the client side to realize non blocking waiting:

main script

```
                //Start Worker 
                    var worker = new Worker('js/worker.js');
                    worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
                        oFoldersInSync[e.data]=true;
                        console.log('Worker said: ', e.data);
                    }, false);
                    worker.postMessage([{
                        param1:<your param1>,
                        param2:<your param2>
                        }]);
```

worker.js

```
self.addEventListener('message', async function(e) {
    //Set Input Params
        var param 1= e.data[0].param1;
        var param2= e.data[0].param2;

    //Init S3
        caonst result = await <your API call>                   
            //Report "done"
                self.postMessage(result);
        }
    close();
}, false);
```

If it's something that cans be processed in the browser, you can also consider letting the WebWorker do the job an calling the S3 upload from there to save resources on the server side.